# Как организовать считывание файлов в цикле на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

К примеру, у меня есть следующий список с именами файлов:

```
Images = ['1.png','2.png','3.png']
```

Я могу считать каждый файл из него следующим образом:

```
k = 0

while k < 3:
    img = cv2.imread(Images[k])
    k = k + 1
```

Однако если у меня есть 1000 картинок, которые необходимо считать, забивать все их названия в список становится проблемой.

Как можно организовать считывание такого большого объема изображений, избегая составления длинного списка названий?

P.S. Логика подсказывает ввести переменную и вертеть ее в цикле до 1000, но я не знаю, как это применить к названиям, ведь они текстовые, а не численные, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: Файлы называются `1.png,...,10.png,...1000.png` или `0001.png,...0010.png,...1000.png`?

Comment: @Dmitri Chubarov "1.png,...,10.png,...1000.png"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуем вот такой цикл:

```
for k in range(1,1001):
    img = cv2.imread("{id}.png".format(id=k))
    process_image(img)
```

Прежде, чем запускать обработку тысячи файлов, проверим, что имена генерируются правильно:

```
for k in range(1,11):
    print("{id}.png".format(id=k))
```

напечатает

```
1.png
2.png
3.png
4.png
5.png
6.png
7.png
8.png
9.png
10.png
```

Часто для того, чтобы алфавитный порядок сортировки файлов, используемый файловыми менеджерами, соответствовал числовому порядку, имена файлов кодируются с приписыванием нужного количества нулей: `0001.png`,`0002.png`,...,`0010.png` и т.д. Тогда нужно будет указать соответствующий модификатор при форматировании строки:

```
for k in range(1,1001):
    img = cv2.imread("{id:04d}.png".format(id=k))
    process_image(img)
```

Answer (score 7):

Если имена файлов уже в списке, то можно просто напрямую их обойти по одному:

```
for filename in ['1.png','2.png','3.png']:
    process_image(cv2.imread(filename))
```

---

В целом в Питоне, если у вас уже есть коллекция элементов и вы хотите выполнить какое-либо действие с каждым элементом коллекции, то не следует по индексам обращаться:

```
#XXX DO NOT DO IT!
k=0
while k<3:
    do_something(seq[k]) # не делайте так
    k=k+1
```

и `range()` так же не следует использовать:

```
#XXX DO NOT DO IT!
for k in range(len(seq)):
    do_something(seq[k]) # не делайте так
```

вместо этого, обходите коллекцию напрямую:

```
for x in seq:
    do_something(x)
```

---

Чтобы выполнить действие над файлами, имена которых определённому шаблону подчиняются, то можно использовать `glob`, `fnmatch`, `re` модули. К примеру, чтобы обработать все `.png` файлы в текущей директории:

```
from glob import glob

for filename in glob('*.png'):
    process_image(cv2.imread(filename))
```

Или чтобы обработать только те имена, которые из одних цифр состоят (не учитывая расширения `.png`) в Питоне 3:

```
import os
import re

for entry in os.scandir():
    if re.fullmatch(r'\d+.png', entry.name):
        process_image(cv2.imread(entry.path))
```

Comment: Вы же добавили расширение в конце .png Поправьте

Comment: @KitScribe: о каком примере говорите? Что вы ожидаете он должен делать? И что он по вашему вместо этого делает?

Comment: Вы написали, что поиск любых файлов без расширения, а сами добавили в fullmatch .png (последний сниппет)

Comment: @KitScribe: поправил для ясности (я имел в виду, что имя из одних цифр состоит, если на расширение не смотреть).

Answer (score 6):

**os.listdir(path)** вернёт вам список всего, что находится в директории **path**, включая папки. Далее нужно пройтись по этому списку и проверить, что вы сейчас работаете с изображением:

```
import os

fds = sorted(os.listdir('/home/username/Images/'))

for img in fds:
    if img.endswith(('.jpg', '.png')): # если имя оканчивается на что-то из tuple...
        print(img) # выводим имя файла
```

Если же вам нужно искать изображения по строгим паттернам, то для этого лучше использовать регулярные выражения, но явно не циклы. Использовать для такого циклы - очень неправильно. С помощью регулярных выражений вашу задачу можно решить таким образом:

```
import os
import re

path = '/home/username/Images'

fds = sorted(os.listdir(path))

for img in fds:
    if re.match(r'\b\d+(.jpg|.png)\b', img):
        print(img) # выводим имя файла
'''
Я создал 25 изображений в домашней директории и пронумеровал их

от 000.png
до 024.png

Вот такой вывод получился у меня
000.png
001.png
002.png
...
022.png
023.png
024.png
'''
```

В такой паттерн поиска попадут все строки (имена файлов), которые начинаются на число, содержат в себе только числа количеством от 1 до бесконечности и заканчиваются либо на `.png`, либо на `.jpg`.

Чтобы открыть файл, нужно будет добавить к имени файла путь до него. Сделать это можно с помощью библиотеки `os`, точнее с помощью `os.path.join()`.

Данная функция склеивает пути специфически для операционной системы. То есть, например, на `Windows` он будет склеивать пути с помощью `\`, а на `Linux` - с помощью `/`.

В данном случае это будет делаться следующим образом:

```
import os
import re

path = '/home/username/Images'

fds = sorted(os.listdir(path))

for img in fds:
    if re.match(r'\b\d+(.jpg|.png)\b', img):
        print(img) # выводим имя файла
        print(os.path.join(path, img) # выводим абсолютный путь
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57363/discussion-on-answer-by-kit-scribe-------).

Answer (score 5):

Предложу еще 1 вариант:

```
from glob import glob
for i in glob('*.png')+glob('*.jpg'):
    print(i)
```

У меня завалялась кучка изображений, вот **результат**:

```
f.png
world.png
Без названия.png
МАТ.png
ACVvPlB3iNY.jpg
cCf06Bjxd0o.jpg
fEclEQ_LN2g.jpg
QMfA4mJH0J0.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю пример через [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

d = Path(<путь до папки с картинками>)

for f in d.glob('*.png'):
    print(f)
```

Отличие в том, что методы `Path` вернут объекты `Path`, например в `f` будет не строка, а объект и у него [есть методы, что в `os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module).

Если нужно получить строковой путь (это не обязательно для стандартных библиотек и функций - они `Path` понимают), то достаточно обернуть в строку: `print(str(f))`

---

**PS.**

Часто бывает, что нужно получить путь в текущей папке скрипта (и помимо использования активных директорий), можно сделать так:

```
DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
DIR_IMAGES = DIR / 'images'
```

В `DIR` будет текущая папка скрипта, а в `DIR_IMAGES` путь к папке `images` в текущей папке скрипта